# How to connect to a SQL Server Compact from a .NET application?

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net, sql-server-ce, database-connection

I would like to create a WPF application that is using a local database. I have created a simple database and added it so I can see my database `NameDB.sdf` in my Solution Explorer.

How do I connect to it from my application?

I have tried with an empty application that just tries to connect to the database:

```
...
using System.Data.SqlServerCe;
using System.Data;

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        SqlCeConnection connection =
            new SqlCeConnection(@"Data Source=|DataDirectory|\NameDB.sdf");
        SqlCeCommand command = new SqlCeCommand("SELECT * FROM Names");
        SqlCeDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlCeDataAdapter(command);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        dataAdapter.Fill(ds);
        Console.WriteLine("Done");
    }
}
```

But I get `XamlParseException` with this message:

> 'The invocation of the constructor on type 'WpfDBApp.MainWindow' that matches the specified binding constraints threw an exception.' Line number '3' and line position '9'.

My connection string is `@"Data Source=|DataDirectory|\NameDB.sdf"`, since I want to use a "local" path and not a full path. This is taken from the tutorial I link to below.

How can I create a simple application that connects to the local database?

I have tried to follow [SQL Server 2005 Compact Edition Data Access with the SqlCeResultSet and Visual C#.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb219485.aspx) but it doesn't seem to be done the same way with [Visual Studio 2010 and WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3125963/data-components-in-visual-studio-are-disabled-how-to-enable-them).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You did not initialized your connection.

```
SqlCeCommand command = new SqlCeCommand("SELECT * FROM Names", connection);
```

Try now.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your connection string. The format should be "Data Source="{FullPath to YourDatabase.sdf}"

See [this MSDN example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlserverce.sqlceconnection.connectionstring(VS.80).aspx) for more details

Comment: I don't want to use a FullPath, I want to use a local path. I have changed the connection string to `new SqlCeConnection(@"Data Source=|DataDirectory|\NameDB.sdf");` but it doesn't work.

Comment: "You can't get there from here"... You have to use a full path because the SQL server isn't running in the context of your application, and does not know the local directory.  You have to dig out the full path.