# Text Delimited into SQL Server CE

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008, sql-server-ce, csv

I have a comma delimited text file which I would like to add to a SQL Server CE database, I know how to do this in SQL Server but not for SQL Server CE using VB.Net.

Will it be a case of having to loop through each line in the file? It's quite a large file.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, first I would use the [textfieldparser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser.aspx) to import the file.  Next, you should only have to configure the connection for your SQLCE db and treat it like a normal SQL db from there.  Here is a snippet from [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127142/how-to-connect-to-a-sql-server-compact-from-a-net-application):

```
Imports System.Data.SqlServerCe
Imports System.Data

Dim connection As New SqlCeConnection("Data Source=|DataDirectory|\<yourdb>.sdf")
Dim command As New SqlCeCommand("SELECT * FROM Names", connection)
Dim dataAdapter As New SqlCeDataAdapter(command)
Dim ds As New DataSet()
dataAdapter.Fill(ds)
```